# Django form doesn't show up

Tags: python, html, django, forms, post

I'm working on some project and ended up with some issues.
So my form doesn't display itself at all in my template.
But I've created another form before and it works as it should!

So my code:

**models.py**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "project"

    COLORS = (
        ('R', 'Red'),
        ('B', 'Blue'),
        ('G', 'Green'),
        ('Y', 'Yellow')
     )
    project_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    project_color = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=COLORS)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_title
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProjectForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['project_title', 'project_color']
```

**views.py**

```
def addproject(request):
    if request.POST:
        form_p = ProjectForm(request.POST)
        if form_p.is_valid():
            form_p.save(commit=False)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
   else:
        form_p = ProjectForm()
    context = {
        'projects': Project.objects.all(),
        "form": form_p,
        'username': auth.get_user(request).username,
    }
    context.update(csrf(request))
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^addproject/$', views.addproject, name='addproject'),]
```

**index.html**

```
<form action="/addproject/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form_p.as_table }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Project</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You have type with your context variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is within your template, you are calling your context variable as **form_p** while passing it as **"form"**:

**index.html**

```
<form action="/addproject/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_table }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Project</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! But now it shows another form that I've created before. What should I do?

Comment: @AnnieShlepak I believe that is happening due to `context.update(csrf(request))` being called after the creation of your context *dict*, not sure right now

Answer (score 2):

**Make sure you are using "ModelForm" instead "Form"**

```py
class NewAccountForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NewAccount
        fields = ('name',)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the form in to the views.py?
place this in to your views.py

```
from .forms import ProjectForm
```